# Make WinJS.UI.Flyout expand upward

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have a `WinJS.UI.Flyout` that I would like to have expand upward when content is added to it while it is visible.  The flyout's anchor is at the bottom of the screen.  If I call `flyout.show(anchor, 'top');` it appears correctly at first, but then expands off the bottom of the screen when content is added.  If I call `flyout.show(anchor, 'bottom');` it expands upward, but it also covers over the anchor element, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using -ms-flexbox display for the flyout and packing its content to the end.

flyout background can be set to transparent; it's size can be set to max possible; this way it serves as a outer container which aligns its content to the end. expandable content is placed inside another div `flyout-content` with background as white.

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout" id="flyout">
    <div class="flyout-content">
        expandable content here
        expandable content here
        expandable content here
        expandable content here
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#flyout
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack: end;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
}

.flyout-content
{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: That definitely got the appearance I wanted, but the preset `height` on the `#flyout` means there is an invisible section in the app where tapping does not close the flyout.  Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: this is definitely a workaround. `#flyout` itself can capture the click event, and if it is the target - hide itself. but that is stretching the workaround further.